# Trying to figure out logic to randomly select an item from a list use the value of the return to randomly select an item from another list. Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still fresh with python and coding in general and I am trying to understand the logic of how to do something. I'm creating a script to randomly chose a game from a console(list) and a game(list) from the said console. For example, I want to randomly select from three or four consoles, and once a console is selected randomly pick a game from that console. I have tried making a function I have no idea how to do it, as I am terrible very new to programming.

```
import random

# List of Console one owns 
console = [ "NES" , "SNES" ]
# A list of each game one would want to play for each console
NES = [ "Contra" , "Metroid" , "Mega Man" , "Mega Man 2" , "Mega Man 3" , "Mega Man 4" , "Mega Man 5" , "Mega Man 6" , "Ninja Gaiden", "Ninja Gaiden 2" , "Strider" ]
SNES = [ "Act Raiser" , "Chrono Trigger ", "F-Zero" , "Final Fantasy 2|4" , " Final Fantasy 3|6" , "The legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past" , "Super Mario RPG" , "Super Metroid"]

# To be added in later 
# List of Genre one might wan to play 
genre = ["Action" , "Action-Adventure" , "RPG" , "Sports"]

#Fucntion to select a random game from all games Available"
S_console = random.choices(console)
S_game = random.choices(S_console)
```

Comment: Did you read about `if`/`else` statements already in your learning materials?

Comment: @homebrewzero You could look into representing your data using a Python dictionary. That would be useful in fetching the games for the chosen console. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

First off, welcome! I like your question. Your title might be a little excessively long, but you presented your question in an understandable way and provided your own attempt to solve it. Well done so far :)

So, let me give you some feedback.

- You want to select only a single item, so `random.choice` is probably better suited than `random.choices`
- You don't actually do anything with the `NES` and `SNES` variables. In order to get an actual game at the end, you need to actually read those.

I think the biggest mistake that you make in your code is that you assume that the string `"NES"` and the variable `NES` are somehow connected. They are not, one is a string with the content `"NES"`, and the other one is a variable named `NES`. Those don't have anything to do with each other. So your second `random.choices` does not work, because its not actually iterating over the variable `NES`, but instead over the string `"NES"`.

I further suspect that this is why you chose `random.choices()` instead of `random.choice()`, because `random.choice()` gave you the error message that you cannot use a variable of type string as the input for `choice()`. So you actually hid the real problem by using `choices` instead of fixing it.

From the back of my head I see two ways that you could connect the choice of console to the actual list of console games:

1. Map it manually with `if` statements
2. Restructure your data structure to better represent the fact that those lists are hierarchical.

---

With if statements:

```
import random

# List of Console one owns 
console = [ "NES" , "SNES" ]
# A list of each game one would want to play for each console
NES = [ "Contra" , "Metroid" , "Mega Man" , "Mega Man 2" , "Mega Man 3" , "Mega Man 4" , "Mega Man 5" , "Mega Man 6" , "Ninja Gaiden", "Ninja Gaiden 2" , "Strider" ]
SNES = [ "Act Raiser" , "Chrono Trigger ", "F-Zero" , "Final Fantasy 2|4" , " Final Fantasy 3|6" , "The legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past" , "Super Mario RPG" , "Super Metroid"]

# To be added in later 
# List of Genre one might wan to play 
genre = ["Action" , "Action-Adventure" , "RPG" , "Sports"]

#Function to select a random game from all games available
S_console = random.choice(console)
print(f"Console: {S_console}")

S_game = ""
if S_console == "NES":
    S_game = random.choice(NES)
elif S_console == "SNES":
    S_game = random.choice(SNES)
print(f"Game: {S_game}")
```

https://ideone.com/VYZSEo

---

With a better data structure:

```
import random
# Dictionary of consoles one owns, together with games for that console
consoles = {
    "NES": ["Contra", "Metroid", "Mega Man", "Mega Man 2", "Mega Man 3", "Mega Man 4", "Mega Man 5", "Mega Man 6", "Ninja Gaiden", "Ninja Gaiden 2", "Strider"],
    "SNES": ["Act Raiser", "Chrono Trigger ", "F-Zero", "Final Fantasy 2|4", " Final Fantasy 3|6", "The legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past", "Super Mario RPG", "Super Metroid"]
}

# Function to select a random game from all games available
S_console = random.choice(list(consoles.keys()))
S_game = random.choice(consoles[S_console])
print(f"Console: {S_console}")
print(f"Game: {S_game}")
```

https://ideone.com/dTJF9p

---

### Edit:

After realizing that the only reason you made the elements of the `console` array strings was that you got an error otherwise, here is what you probably *intended* to write:

```
import random

# A list of each game one would want to play for each console
NES = [ "Contra" , "Metroid" , "Mega Man" , "Mega Man 2" , "Mega Man 3" , "Mega Man 4" , "Mega Man 5" , "Mega Man 6" , "Ninja Gaiden", "Ninja Gaiden 2" , "Strider" ]
SNES = [ "Act Raiser" , "Chrono Trigger ", "F-Zero" , "Final Fantasy 2|4" , " Final Fantasy 3|6" , "The legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past" , "Super Mario RPG" , "Super Metroid"]
# List of Console one owns 
console = [ NES , SNES ]

# To be added in later 
# List of Genre one might wan to play 
genre = ["Action" , "Action-Adventure" , "RPG" , "Sports"]

#Fucntion to select a random game from all games Available"
S_console = random.choice(console)
S_game = random.choice(S_console)
```

https://ideone.com/vWLVVd

If you set `NES` and `SNES` *before* `console`, you can use them as members of the array.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. So the reason I used random.choices() was when I was trying out and running the code, I got the same result every time, so when I changed from random.choice() to random.choices(), the result changed every time I ran it in juypter notebook. It did cross my mind that one was a string and one was a variable; however, when I started the list, I needed to use the quotes, or I would get an error. Thanks for the feedback, and I found this very helpful.

Comment: After I get this working, I'll want to pull it from a CSV or excel file. hopefully, the resources I find online will help me with this problem.

Comment: You **can** put the `NES` variable into the `consoles` list, but then you need to define the `NES` viariable **before** you put it in the list. Definitions go from top to bottom, you cannot reference variables that you define later.

Comment: @homebrewzero Added your intended code as a third solution, if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used `choices` I'll assume you're clear on simple sampling for a list. NB, there is an important difference between picking with and without replacement, and Python has functions for both.

In your case you not only need to choose a random game from a list (the technical term is *population*) but you have several populations (one for each console) and the population must also be chosen at random.

You are picking the console names at random, but there's not an easy way in Python to say "get the variable with the name matching this string". There's a way to do it, but generally it's simpler to write your program in such a way that if the variables were all renamed without altering any constants, it would still work.

The simple solution is a list of lists. We can modify the code you have like so:

```
# Each console's population
NES = [ "Contra" , "Metroid" , "Mega Man" , "Mega Man 2" , "Mega Man 3" , "Mega Man 4" , "Mega Man 5" , "Mega Man 6" , "Ninja Gaiden", "Ninja Gaiden 2" , "Strider" ]
SNES = [ "Act Raiser" , "Chrono Trigger ", "F-Zero" , "Final Fantasy 2|4" , " Final Fantasy 3|6" , "The legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past" , "Super Mario RPG" , "Super Metroid"]

# Make list of populations
allpops = [NES, SNES]

# Pick random pop
thispop = random.choice(u)

# Pick random game from this pop
S_game = random.choices(thispop)
```

This as an alternate, equivalent way of defining the list of lists:

```
# Make list of populations
allpops = [
    [ "Contra" , "Metroid" , "Mega Man" , "Mega Man 2" , "Mega Man 3" , "Mega Man 4" , "Mega Man 5" , "Mega Man 6" , "Ninja Gaiden", "Ninja Gaiden 2" , "Strider" ],
    [ "Act Raiser" , "Chrono Trigger ", "F-Zero" , "Final Fantasy 2|4" , " Final Fantasy 3|6" , "The legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past" , "Super Mario RPG" , "Super Metroid"]
]
```

The problem here is that the names of each population disappear, because there's not a direct way of attaching a name to elements of a list. So you lose the ability to tell the user which console was picked, they only know the game.

If you do care about the console, you can use a dictionary. It's a similar idea to the list of lists, except each element can now have a key (there are also important performance implications).

```
allpops = {
    "NES': [ "Contra" , "Metroid" , "Mega Man" , "Mega Man 2" , "Mega Man 3" , "Mega Man 4" , "Mega Man 5" , "Mega Man 6" , "Ninja Gaiden", "Ninja Gaiden 2" , "Strider" ],
    "SNES": [ "Act Raiser" , "Chrono Trigger ", "F-Zero" , "Final Fantasy 2|4" , " Final Fantasy 3|6" , "The legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past" , "Super Mario RPG" , "Super Metroid"]
}

# Chose random console
console = random.choice(allpops)
thispop = allpops[console]

# Choose random game
game = random.choice(thispop)
```

Since you want to do genre as well, you would have to do something like a dictionary of console to dictionary of genre to game and do 3 rounds of selection.